# Samurai Sword Rising Sun: Ninjas Finding Ronin

Tags: samurai-sword

My question is regarding the strategy to identify Ronin in Samurai Sword Rising Sun. In this expansion pack of Samurai Sword, there are 2 Ronins, 2 Samurais, 3 Ninjas and 1 Shogun. The Shoguns and the Samurais will be targeting players that are hitting them. However, how can the ninjas know (or guess) who the Ronins are? To play safe the Ninjas will keep targeting Shogun and Samurai but no one will be able to find Ronin. Won't this make the whole game one sided where Ninjas and Ronins are just targeting Samurais and Shogun?

Comment: I think you are missing some of the strategy involved in the game. There is no reason why teammates will not also target other teammates depending on the situation. For example a Samurai may target the Shogun when they are in danger of running out of resilience in order to keep the honor point on their team. It should be remembered that unlike bang there can be some great advantage in attacking a teammate.